# Двойной поиск объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объекты с конкретный тегом (к примеру препятствия), и в какой-то момент мне нужно их удалить, но удалять мне нужно конкретные объекты, то есть те которых имеют тег (препятствия) и еще что-то то что нужно мне, можно ли дать второй тег объекту или нет? просто по имени они создаются как Cube(1) вместо Cube

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант: делите препятствия по группам, которые надо удалить, и кидаете их в пустой объект, ему тег присваиваете "delete1", или наоборот, каждому объекту даете дочерний объект со своим тегом, и при коллизии (или чего там у вас) проверяете на тэг (кстати, [GameObject.CompareTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html), работает быстрее, чем сравнение тэгов ( [GameObject.tag="lala"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html)) и [проверяете родителя](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html), либо проверяете ещё и [имя объекта](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html), как вариант - разделите на [слои](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html). Ещё (ну как 
 вариант) можете каждому объекту скрипт повесить "RemovalCondition" и через [GameObject.GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)
Внутри класса сделать public свойство (или, что менее предпочтительно, public поле)

```
 RemovalCondition agaga;
 agaga = GameObject.GetComponent<RemovalCondition>();
 agaga.MyBool=true;
```

.
(ну или enum и т.д.) В общем все зависит от того, что вы хотите, а реализация может быть разной.

Answer (score -1):

```
GameObject ObjectsWithTag[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag<TAG>();
Destroy (ObjectsWithTag);
```